# On tumblr, how do I code a frame around my header?

Tags: header, blogs, frame, tumblr

Here is my tumblr blog: 
[thestorywithnoending.tumblr.com](http://thestorywithnoending.tumblr.com)

I want a frame around the image header, so that the content disapears when I scroll down,
but the header stays in place...

just like this blog:

[tiredskin.tumblr.com](http://tiredskin.tumblr.com)

but I cant figure out how to do this,

please help,

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need to do.. Replace this in your current code

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 

&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 


</style>
<body>
<p><center><a href="http://thestorywithnoending.tumblr.com"><img src="http://michaeljamess.webs.com/blogheader.png" border="0"/></a></center>
</p>
```

with this

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
 float: left;
 margin-left:338px;
 width: 500px;
 height: 100px;
 font-size: 11px;
 text-align:left;
 position:fixed;
 background-color:none;
 padding:0px;
 z-index:999;
 top:0px;
}
#content{
 margin-top:300px!important;
}
</style>
<div id="left">
  <center>
   <a href="http://thestorywithnoending.tumblr.com">
     <img src="http://michaeljamess.webs.com/blogheader.png" border="0"/>
   </a>
  </center>
</div>
```

p.s if it solved your problem, mark it as the best answer :)